# How to remove comments column in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am new to wordpress. I choose Twenty Twenty Theme for my use. In that I want to remove email & Website text box.

But I am not sure where I can edit that. Please help me to solve this issue

Attached screen shot of my comments section
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this code it is working.

```
function name_email_remove($fields) {
    if(isset($fields['email']) && isset($fields['author']))
    unset($fields['email']);
    unset($fields['author']);
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'name_email_remove');
```

If you want to remove the website URL too then use $fields['url'].

Let me know if any questions.

Comment: where I need to add this snippet ? I mean in which file ?

Comment: @Rajesh Kumar your active themes functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution to stop commenting
[image]